# Is there any freely available English translation of the Peṭakopadesa?

Tags: pali-canon

I only have knowledge of [Ñāṇamoli's translation](http://www.palitext.com/palitext/tran.htm#tt37) which is not available for free. Does anyone have knowledge of an English translation available for free?

Comment: looking to see more questions and answers from you.

Answer (score 2):

The Pali Text Society is about the best authority for English translations, and they did produce a reference text in 1977. There is not a lot of online translations, but here is a link to the digital version of the book:

http://lirs.ru/lib/The_Guide,Nettippakarana,Nanamoli,1977.pdf

Comment: That is the *Netti*, not the *Peṭakopadesa*, and there is already an answer that mentions that link. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find it at [http://tipitaka.sutta.org/](http://tipitaka.sutta.org/en_US/canon/sutta/khuddaka/pe%E1%B9%ADakopadesa/suttatthasamuccayabh%C5%ABmi) , not sure about the quality of translation.

Comment: I couldn't find anything there. Did you find it? If you didn't find it yourself and were uncertain that it was available, why did you answer? I know you may have had a good intention but this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Sorry thats the best i can find you do need to read word by word whith the built in dictionary function which cant get all the words in that particular book :(

Answer (score 0):

This book claims to compare
The Nettippakarana and Petakopadesa, compared - xiii. 6. Authorship and ... Glossary (Pali-English). 288 ... The book here translated—as it stands, it was perhaps composed ..... The only extra source available is the contents of the two books.

lirs.ru/lib/The_Guide,Nettippakarana,Nanamoli,1977.pdf

This is a free resource. Hope that is of interest

Comment: I've already skimmed through that one. I was looking for a complete *Peṭakopadesa* but thank you for the notification on that specific *Netti* chapter. It's very enlightening about their similarities & differences.